# Turning PCA output into dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, pca

I've run a principal components analysis. The output pca1$loadings looks like a dataframe, but it's not. Is there a way to turn this into a dataframe?

I'd like to be able to sort the columns of the output. It would also be nice if I could use the output in Excel.

This is the code I used to generate the PCA.

```
cor <- cor(df[, 1:87]) #correlation matrix with all dv's
pca1 <- principal(cor, nfactors = 87, rotate = "varimax") 
pca1$loadings
```

Comment: You can just use `write.csv(pca1$loadings, "PCA_loading.csv")` for writing the PCA loadings in .csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is of class `loadings`, to convert to dataframe use `as.data.frame.matrix`

```
pca1 <- psych::principal(cor, nfactors = 87, rotate = "varimax")$loadings 
as.data.frame.matrix(pca1)
```

Using reproducible example with `mtcars`

```
cor <- cor(mtcars)
pca1 <- psych::principal(cor, nfactors =2, rotate = "varimax")$loadings 
as.data.frame.matrix(pca1)


#         RC1     RC2
#mpg   0.6846 -0.6329
#cyl  -0.6373  0.7231
#disp -0.7328  0.6044
#hp   -0.3233  0.8828
#drat  0.8533 -0.2091
#wt   -0.7989  0.4557
#qsec -0.1591 -0.8996
#vs    0.2996 -0.8206
#am    0.9206  0.0774
#gear  0.9066  0.1661
#carb  0.0775  0.8660
```

---

A shorter version is to just remove the class attribute

```
unclass(pca1)
```

Comment: as.data.frame.matrix() works when I use pca1$loadings, not when I just use pca1.

Comment: @melbez yes, that what I am doing in `pca1 <- psych::principal(cor, nfactors = 87, rotate = "varimax")$loadings`.